# Get reference to object from c# expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, expression

I have an extension generic method

```
public static void AddError<TModel>(
    this ModelStateDictionary modelState, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression, 
    string resourceKey, 
    string defaultValue)
{
    // How can I get a reference to TModel object from expression here?
}
```

I need to get the reference to TModel object from expression.
This method called by the following code:

```
ModelState.AddError<AccountLogOnModel>(
    x => x.Login, "resourceKey", "defaultValue")
```

Comment: There is no such object in an expression – `x` is a parameter of the expression, you're supposed to pass an object of the type into it. (Or I'm understanding what you want to achieve wrongly.)

Comment: Do you really want the object or the text `Login` to use for the `AddModelError(key, errorMessage)` method? Use `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` (built in to MVC) to get the property name from a lambda expression.

Comment: @subkamran you probably meant `lambda expression`...

Comment: I need the reference to TModel object ) I don't want to pass another param with reference to object )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get to the TModel object itself without passing it into the method. The expression you are passing in is only saying "take this property from a TModel". It isn't actually providing a TModel to operate on. So, I would refactor the code to something like this:

```
public static void AddError<TModel>(
    this ModelStateDictionary modelState, 
    TModel item,
    Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression, 
    string resourceKey, 
    string defaultValue)
{
    // TModel's instance is accessible through `item`.
}
```

Then your calling code would look something like this:

```
ModelState.AddError<AccountLogOnModel>(
    currentAccountLogOnModel, x => x.Login, "resourceKey", "defaultValue")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I don't see another way also. I done this already yesterday in my code ^)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you really want the text "Login" to use to add a new model error to the `ModelStateDictionary`.

```
public static void AddError<TModel>(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, 
  Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression, string resourceKey, string defaultValue)
{
    var propName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

    modelState.AddModelError(propName, GetResource("resourceKey") ?? defaultValue);
}
```

Assume you have some resource factory/method that returns `null` if the resource isn't found, that's just for illustration.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i need to save my error data such as resource key and default value into modelState object and TModel object. With expression i pass property to which error data related, that should be saved into TModel object. )

Comment: To do that, you'll need to pass in the actual object as a parameter. A generic is not the object reference itself.