# ModelState.AddModelError to a particular ValidationMessageFor of a field?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code to generate an html input and validation message.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
......
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUpload, new { type = "file", name = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageUpload)
</div>
```

In my action I have the code

```
if (.... something wrong with the input ....) 
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid image file.");
    return RedirectToAction(....
```

However, it will show an error message in the validation summary section. Is it possible to show the error message in the validation message section for input too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to provide a key:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "Invalid image file.");
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. Check out [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688082/validationmessagefor-together-with-addmodelerrorkey-message-whats-the-key).

Comment: The "key" is the name of the input field as specified in the `ValidationMessageFor` statement.

Comment: So loop through the error messages in the validation result then add each one like: ModelState.AddModelError(errorMessage.PropertyName, errorMessage.ErrorMessage)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer the OPs original question, but what I was looking for was the ability to add a model error to the ModelState for a control on my form that was not part of the model. The way to do that is to add a ValidationMessage helper to the page which you can reference in the AddModelError call by name.
Example:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
......
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input name="FileName" />
    @Html.ValidationMessage("FileNameValidation")
</div>
```

Then, in your controller action, you can do:

```
if (.... something wrong with the input ....) 
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("FileNameValidation", "Please fix the File Name.");
    return View( viewModel );
}
```

Hope this helps someone with a slightly different situation.